# Creating pattern using simple loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am trying to create this pattern in python:

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
```

This is my program so far that I've come up with:

```
ster = "*"
space = " "
lines = 0
n = 3
x = 1
while lines <= 5:
    print space*n, ster*x
    n-= 1
    x+= 1
    lines += 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well, to begin: why do you think this code would accomplish the creation of that pattern?

Comment: @n1c9 that is the problem now isnt it?

Comment: @n1c9 that is what im asking, how can i correct my code?

Comment: I think what n1c9 is trying to say is that, looking at your code, do you understand what you are doing and if not what are you doing? I think rather than getting a straight answer from us, we want you to learn and understand what you are doing. A good starting point is commenting in your code with `#` and putting down what you want, and how it can be achieved, break it down into smaller parts and code the comments.

Comment: what I meant by my comment is essentially what @MooingRawr said - I know you're here for help, but you need to be a little more descriptive in *why* you think this code should accomplish that goal.  This code runs, it just doesn't produce the pattern you're after.

Comment: (following @MooingRawr)...as well as showing what output you're getting, which can provide loads of hints.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first of all you can create a list of numbers which represents the number of stars in each line.

```
number_of_stars = 5

i_list = list(range(number_of_stars))
# extend the list by its inverse i_list[::-1]
# but exclude the first item
i_list.extend(i_list[::-1][1:])

print(i_list) # prints: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Now you can go thru the list and print a multiple of `*`

```
for i in i_list:
    print('* ' * i)
```

But this is not aligned properly. By adding multiple empty spaces to the left one can archive a solution:

```
for i in i_list:
    print(' ' * (number_of_stars - i) + '* ' * i)
```

Note that in python one can repeat a string by using the multiplication symbol:

```
print('a'*5) # prints: aaaaa
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the help, I wrote a functional code for the problem. It was supposed to made using while loop(s).
This is what I did:

```
width = int(input("Width: "))

i = 1
while i < width*2:
   if i < width:
       print " " * (width-i) + "* " * i
   else:
       print " " * (i-width) + "* " * (2*width-i)

   i = i + 1
```

Comment: This gives me an infinite loop. Because your indentation of `i = i + 1` needs to be in the loop.

Comment: @MooingRawr it does? I just ran the code, seems to be working fine

Comment: Good job, it works now. Now wasn't that more satisfying than us giving you the answer and you just copying trying to understand it ? Not to sound like a major D or condescending, I just want people to learn things.

Comment: @MooingRawr totally agree, just that sometimes coding can get frustrating real fast

Comment: it's like that for a little bit, then running into problems is actually *fun*, believe it or not. :-) happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Notice you have

- 3 spaces for 1 star
- 2 spaces for 2 stars
- 1 space for 3 stars.

For the upright triangle part of your diamond (including the large part). Then you have

- 2 spaces for 2 stars
- 3 spaces for 1 star

Without throwing out the answer, try analysing a certain pattern in what i've just pointed out. It can be achieved with 2 loops ( for or while, depending on your preference).